# Unable to POST form data when I add name tag to a particular input tag?

Tags: php

I have been struggling to figure out the mystery behind this.

Unable to `POST` form data when I add `name` to a particular `input` field. I been starring at the screen for hours to figure out what went wrong.

My Code goes as,

**Form Page:**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST">

<div class="customer_records">
    <div class="customer_records_sub">
        <input type="text" list="o_id" name="o_id[]" class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 o_id_input" placeholder="Order ID" 
                style="width: auto;padding: 10px 50px;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;
                                          border: 1px solid lightgray;border-radius:5px;vertical-align: text-bottom;background: none;">
        <datalist id="o_id">
            <?php
                $sql_o_id = "SELECT DISTINCT(o_id) FROM quotes";
                $result_o_id = $conn->query($sql_o_id);
                if ($result_o_id->num_rows > 0) {   
                while($row_o_id = $result_o_id->fetch_assoc()) { 
                    $o_id = $row_o_id["o_id"];
            ?>
                <option value="<?= $o_id; ?>">
            <?php } } else { } ?>
        </datalist>

        <div class="asins_visible_input mb-2 mr-sm-2" 
            style="width: auto;padding: 10px 50px;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;
                   border: 1px solid lightgray;border-radius:5px;vertical-align: text-bottom;
                   background: none;height: 45px;min-width: 300px;" >
        </div>
        <br/>
                            
        <div class="asins_list" style="display:none;height: auto;overflow: auto;width: auto;
                                border: 1px solid lightgray;padding: 2%;border-radius: 5px;
                                margin-left: 24%;min-width: 400px;">
            <?php 
                $sql_asin_id = "SELECT * FROM quotespos";
                $result_asin_id = $conn->query($sql_asin_id);
                if ($result_asin_id->num_rows > 0) {   
                while($row_asin_id = $result_asin_id->fetch_assoc()) { 
                    $asin_id = $row_asin_id["id"];
                    $asin_p_id = $row_asin_id["p_id"];
                    $asin_o_id = $row_asin_id["o_id"];
                    if($asin_p_id == '' || $asin_p_id == NULL) {
                        $asin_p_id = '(BLANK)';
                    } else {
                        $asin_p_id = $asin_p_id;
                    }
            ?>
                <div class="asin_id indi_asin_<?= $asin_o_id; ?>" style="display:none;padding-left:10px;">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="asins_input_checkbox" data-id="<?= $asin_id; ?>" data-pid="<?= $asin_p_id; ?>" style="display:inline-block;width: 20px;height: 20px;" /> 
                    <p style="display:inline-block;padding-top: 2px;font-size: 16px;vertical-align: super;"><?= $asin_p_id; ?></p>
                                  
                    <div class="asins_div_percentile" 
style="diplay:inline-block;float:right;display:none;">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" 
                            style="margin-top: 9px;margin-left: 8px;font-size: 14px;"></i>
                                      
                        <input class="asins_div_percentile_input" name="tada"
                            style="width: 50px;margin-left: 30px;vertical-align: top;
                                    border: 1px solid gray;font-size: 16px;
                                    border-radius:5px;border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;" 
                                    type="text" placeholder="%" />
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                <?php $sl++; } } else { } ?>
                              
                <input type="hidden" name="asins[]" class="asins_hidden_input" />
            </div>
                              
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <input type="hidden" name="bywhom" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="06/12/201" />

    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 expense_form_btn" 
              style="margin-top: 0.8%;font-size:16px;">Submit</button>
                        
</form>
```

**Upload.php page:**

```
$date = $_POST["date"];
$bywhom = $_POST["bywhom"];

echo $bywhom;
```

[image: Network Payload Screenshot]

In the above form page, forget the array and all, they all work perfectly fine the moment i remove the name tag from the input tag with class `asins_div_percentile_input`, But the moment I keep something inside the name tag of that `asins_div_percentile_input` input, form gets submitted but none of the values gets posted. not even the normal input tag values like `date` mentioned above.

I don't understand what went wrong. Hope I was clear.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before you continue searching for possible other reasons, fix your broken HTML first of all. `p` and `div` can not be nested into a `span`.

Comment: @CBroe Noted. Thanks

Comment: You changed the code in your question. No matter how trivial, you now need to test your code again, to make sure the same problem still exists, with the exact code that you posted here.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I just changed a `<span>` tag to `<div>` that's all

Comment: If the problem still persists, then continue with the next step of a _proper_ problem analysis - do the values not get _send_ in the first place (use browser dev tools, network panel, to check), or is it just the server side having trouble receiving/parsing the request for some reason.

Comment: Check also in browser if there are any syntax errors in source code (show source code). It should be highlighted in red. Such errors can cause part of the form to not post at all.

Comment: @CBroe I have checked the network on the output page to see if the data is being posted or not, And I see that data is being posted but not being echoed for some reason.  Please check the question, have updated it with the **network payload** screenshot. [link](https://ibb.co/51CzCcX). And i also checked the console for form page, none there.

Comment: How many inputs do you have in total? Maybe you're hitting php's max_input_vars

Comment: You have multiple inputs with the same name "tada", because of the loop. Preferably these names should be unique. Also, `var_dump($_POST)`, should show you everything that's being posted.

Comment: Where is that `redirect` parameter coming from, I don't see any form field of that name anywhere in your code. Does this form get submitted normally, or is JavaScript/AJAX/fetch involved?

Comment: @CBroe Please ignore the `$redirect` was just testing with other values, and the form is doesn't involve any JS , its just plain HTML form to PHP post. 

And I also checked the php's `max_input_vars` limit in php.ini, it's set to 50,000.

Comment: @EliasSoares Was right, the issue was with max_input_vars of PHP. I just limited the query to 100, now it posts the data just fine. But I did change the `max_input_vars` to 50k, wonder why didn't it worked.. ?

Comment: Maybe you are changing the wrong php conf file. use phpinfo() to check the loaded configuration files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking a bit, I found a way around. Instead of forcing it to send all the empty fields and then take only the fields which have values, I removed the empty fields from DOM at the time of submission.

```
$(".form_submit_btn").click(function() {
    $(".form_submit_btn").prop("disabled", true);
    $('.main_parent').find('.asins_input_checkbox').each(function () {
        if($(this).prop("checked")) { } else {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }
    });
    $("#add_expense_form").submit();
});
```

Works fine. Thanks to all who literally taught me a lot through this query. Appreciate your time.